# Missing Texture Color

Tags: texturing

This may be a bit OCD from me, but whenever I see people mention the *pink* missing textures I yell *magenta* (and get strange looks from my family). I have looked in the manual, but can not find any reference to the color. There also does not seem to be a preference to change the default missing texture color. Finally I have also tried to get it from a Blender output itself, but this depends on the lighting/settings etc.

Does anyone know how to get the actual RGB values for the missing textures, ignoring lights, shadows etc? I need to know if I am a crazy or just crazy smart.

Comment: Hello :).You're right, it really is pure Magenta *(rgb:255,0,255)*. Just plug the *image texture node* directly into the material output. And set color management to *Standard* to see it.

Comment: Thank you very much @JachymMichal - I wouls have accepted this as an answer if I could as I was not aware of that feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The color, that is used when a texture is not found, is defined by four macros in [`texture.h`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/intern/cycles/util/texture.h$12). The color is magenta with full alpha (no transparency).

```
#define TEX_IMAGE_MISSING_R 1
#define TEX_IMAGE_MISSING_G 0
#define TEX_IMAGE_MISSING_B 1
#define TEX_IMAGE_MISSING_A 1
```

<sub>Code is licensed under [Apache 2.0](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/C/browse/master/LICENSE)</sub>

The macros are used whenever image data isn't available, e.g. in `ImageManager::device_load_image()` [`image.cpp`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/intern/cycles/scene/image.cpp) when the loading of an image failed or in `PointDensityTextureNode::compile()` [`shader_nodes.cpp`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/intern/cycles/scene/shader_nodes.cpp) when no texture has been selected in the *Image Texture* node.

Comment: I changed the rgb values, but to no effect. Is there something else I've got to do?

Comment: @FatalBulletHit You have to compile Blender as described in the [wiki](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender).

Comment: ah, was hoping it'd read the file on every launch or so, thanks for the info! :)